# SSIS - Exporting data with commas to a csv file

Tags: ssis

I am trying to export a list of fields to a csv file from a database.
It keeps putting all the data onto one column and doesn't separate it. When checking the preview it seems to be okay but on export its not working. Currently trying to following settings. Any help would be appreciated.

SSIS settings

[image: SSIS setting]

[image: SSIS Settings 2]

Excel file output issue

[image: Excel]

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems to work, Excel is just too dumb to recognize it.
Mark the whole table, then go to Data -> Text in Rows

[image: Text in Rows]

And configure the wizard (Separeted, Semikolon as Separator):
[image]
[image]

Now you have seperated the rows and cells:
[image]

Comment: Hey Andreas, Is there a way to get this automatically into excel without manually doing the text to columns. I'm am trying to automate a file that is picked up by an external source so the users don't manually have to do.

Comment: @tomfbsc I think Excel remembers the last setting. This may differ from user to user. If you want to make sure that Excel opens the file in the correct manner, you have to store the file in a real .xlsx format, not as .csv.

Comment: I ended up switching to comma delimited and now its showing in the correct format.